# Query to join two nested collections in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I'm stuck trying to do a query to retrieve all documents of a collection with the documents of two nested collections. Those are the collections and the query I have so far. Thanks for your help.

https://mongoplayground.net/p/HWOMTpOjMNk

Comment: It is solved. One of the ids contain a character "t" which is incorrect for an id. I have changed it to "c" and all solved.